How to use unity asset store 3d models in SceneKit?
Here's what I have tried:

I downloaded this free asset from unity asset store: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/teddy-suit-kid-95262

The downloaded file is of format .unitypackage.

Then I use this tool https://github.com/SamarthMP/unitypackage-extractor to extract the content, and got this:



I don't know how to precede from here. It'd be great if I can get a single USDZ file for each of the 3d models in this unitypackage, so it's easier to use in SceneKit.

I have not dowloaded this package, but in another package, I used some time ago, the models were stored in FBX format. You cannot use them in SceneKit directly. I recommend you to convert the models to Collada (DAE) format and the textures to PNG format (i.Ex. Blender can do this). Then you can easily use them in SceneKit. You might then convert the DAE to SCN using XCode, this will give you better performance and an easy way to manage the UV textures on the model.

How do i convert the models to DAE? It's not a file, it's a folder.

I do see FBX files under Meshes folder, but when i open it under blender, the textures are not there. I don't know enough about blender to make it work. I have uploaded the folder here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RV_Z3z4Dotke-KOzeaa9cuqu-WWv4vyB?usp=sharing

I recommend you, to watch some Tutorials about how to use Blender for intermediate for file conversation. This here is not the right place to discuss Blender conversion Issues. All I can say, You have everything there you need to make it work in SceneKit. The TGA Texture Files are currently way too big. Use texture sizes of 512 or 1024 max. Use PNG Output (i.Ex with Photoshop). In Blender the textures do not automatically load, you will need to add them, if you want to see them in Blender. But I recommend, to just convert the Model to DAE (Export as ...), and bring all together in  XCode.

"This here is not the right place to discuss Blender conversion Issues." Well this question is not asking about blender conversion issues.
